# Missing files after Debug in VS 2010 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, release

I have a different problem nowadays. As I am developing a program that contains lots of plug-ins, When I debug my program, I see that some of my plugins are not loaded . I have controlled all .dlls and I can see the not installed plugin's .dll in the folder.

Tha problem occurs just on Debug, when I make a Relase I can see all non-existing plugins.

What might be the problem ?

Thank you all

Comment: when you say "not loaded" what do you mean?  How can you tell they are not loaded?

Comment: When a plug-in is well loaded I can see the icon of that. But when I debug i can not see its icon .

Comment: Clearly you need to improve your error logging code?

Answer (score 0):

You have put them in the wrong folder (which is used for release build).
Debug build folder is usually different than Release, so put your dlls there also.

Comment: Then you must debug code and see what happens. At this point could be anything.